# Combobox not sorted after insert a new item sql server ce

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In a Windows Forms application I have a button that adds a new person and a ComboBox that shows all the persons. I made an `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` query to display the persons in alphabetical order and it works only when I first open the window. However, when I add a new persons the ComboBox displays the items in the order they were introduced and I want it to keep the alphabetical order. How can I solve this?

Comment: You should really show us some of your code. It's near impossible to help you without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: Also... For the ComboBox, make Sorted true: `ComboBox.Sorted = true;`

Comment: I have a DataSource and I can't set Sorted property to true.

Comment: Show us the queries.

Comment: INSERT INTO [Persons] ([First Name], [Last Name], [Date], [IdActivity], [IdNomPers]) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname,@idActivity,idNomPers)

Comment: A person is first saved in a table NomPers and each person is related to an activity.

Comment: SELECT IdNomPers, First Name, Last Name FROM NomPers WHERE (IdNomPers=@idNomPers) ORDER BY First Name

Comment: And how are you adding a person to the data source after it is created?

Comment: When I click the Add Button, the person is saved in the NomPers table.

Comment: Then I choose the name from the combobox, complete some other fields and save in the Persons table

Comment: Please share your code, in other case it is really hard to help you.

Comment: Just edit your post with the actual code rather than trying to post SQL Snippets in comments. But it sounds like you're not re-querying the database and re-setting the `DataSource`. As others have said, we need to see the actual **code**, in particular your button click event and whatever else pertinent to your combobox.

Comment: It's ok, I solved it. Thank you

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: it was a Fill method that has a Select query and I added ORDER BY to the query

Answer (score 1):

According to [ComboBox.Sorted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx). This value needs to be set to true in order to sort it.
`The sort is case-insensitive and in alphabetically ascending order.`

`ComboBox.Sorted = true;` just set this value via the designer.